# ArcGIS Pro- no option to add graphic layer

Tags: arcgis-pro

According to the documentation, it should be easy to draw graphics onto a map....

"On the Map tab, in the Layer group, click Add Graphics Layer.
A new graphics layer appears in the Contents pane."

In my Map tab- Layer Group, I only have 'Basemap, Add Data, Add Preset"
I have search for commands, ect but simply can't find a solution.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you do not have 2.6 -- this feature was added in the newly released version (2.6).

See the explanation in the [announcement blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/announcements/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro-2-6) or the official [What's New help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm) topic..

Comment: I suggest Esri adds version info to the Pro help docs - https://community.esri.com/ideas/18856-add-version-information-to-arcgis-pro-helpdocumentation